# How do I get parts of Blacklist checked

Tags: c#, arrays, sql-server, linq, sql-like

```
if (!blacklist.Contains(tabName) && (allowedSchemas.Contains(schName)) )
{
    string schemaname = GetStringFromReader(reader, "SchemaName");
    string tablename = GetStringFromReader(reader, "TableName");
    string description = GetStringFromReader(reader, "Description");
    string columnname = "null";

    tabInfo.Add(new TableInfo(schemaname, tablename, columnname, description));
}
```

this is my Code i have a Problem.
For example i have tabName= BSPname and in my Blacklist= BSP.
So i need to get here a true.

Now it gives me only true if Blacklist == tabName.

So I need sth like in MSSQL: tabName NOT LIKE %@blacklist%

I hope you understand my question

Janik

Comment: structure of blackList

Comment: try the seco0nd solution

Comment: blacklist is an Array with one ore more Strings like String[] blacklist = {"db","ZPR"}

Comment: I updated my answer check it will work for you..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need like this   `tabName NOT LIKE %@blacklist%` than you need to check in string that means you need to apply contains on string as below

```
var match = blacklist.FirstOrDefault(s=>tabName.ToUpper().Contains(s.ToUpper()));
if( match==null && (allowedSchemas.Contains(schName)) )
{
  ..your code
}
```

Comment: oh sorry i'm new here and I thought that i'm not allowed to vote yet

Comment: @I3_SUZO - no need to thanks...you acceptance is equal to thanks...and no need to be sorry